# Debian adding users by itself

Tags: debian, users

I have a debian server with three acounts, root, myself (tobbe) and my colleague (chrille). When I first logged in (via ssh) and ran the command **users** I got:

> root tobbe chrille

An hour later (installing git, phpmyadmin, ruby etc etc...) I'm hearing from my friend that there's multiple users with the same name, running **users** again I get:

> tobbe tobbe tobbe chrille

3 tobbe, 1 chrille and no root.

Thinking it's weird but keeps editing and doing stuff, by running the same command I'm now getting:

> tobbe tobbe tobbe tobbe tobbe tobbe

That being 6 tobbe, no root or chrille. What is happening? Oh and I've been logged into tobbe all the time. I have no idea what's happening :(

Comment: Please read `man users`.  The command lists who is logged on.  If you're logged on with multiple sessions, it will likely list the same user multiple times.  Try the `who` command.

Comment: Oh ok thank you! I'm probably doing something wrong when I'm signing out, isn't **logout** the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Please read `man users`. The command lists who is logged on. If you're logged on with multiple sessions, it will likely list the same user multiple times. Try the `who` command.

`logout` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) is the correct way to log out, but sessions may not disappear for some time, depending on your ssh_config (try `man ssh_config`).